# Object import in Next.JS /api folder is undefined

Tags: node.js, next.js, zod

I am trying to import an object from a separate file in the Next.JS `pages/api` folder.
Importing the schema object works perfectly fine inside any of `.tsx` files for the client.
However, importing the schema using the same import statement in the `/api` folder results in a TypeError.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'safeParse')
```

---

`./types/message.ts`

```js
import { z } from 'zod';

export default interface Message {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  subject: string;
  message: string;
}

export const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  email: z.string().email(),
  subject: z.string(),
  message: z.string(),
});
```

`/pages/form.tsx`

```
...
import Message, { schema } from '@/types/message';
const { register, handleSubmit} = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
  });
...
```

`./pages/api/sendMessage.ts`

```js
...
import Message, { schema } from '@/types/message';

...
// The TypeError is thrown when this line is executed.
const response = schema.safeParse(req.body);
...
```

---

I have also tried importing the schema object using require without any success.

Copying the schema definition into the *`sendMessage`* file fixes the error. To avoid code duplication, I would, however, prefer to keep the schema definition in a separate file.

`./pages/api/sendMessage.ts`

```js
import { z } from 'zod';
...
const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  email: z.string().email(),
  subject: z.string(),
  message: z.string(),
});
...
```